# Place a timer in a Xamarin Carousel page

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin, carousel, system.timers.timer

I would like to place a timer in a Xamarin Forms carousel page, to make the 'swipe' happen automatically if the user does nothing.

Being new to Xamarin I'm not entirely sure if I can do this as I would outwith Xamarin, by creating a System.Timer in code-behind.

The auto swipe should happen after 3 seconds, and swipe through the carousel at 3 second intervals.

Can anyone tell me if this is a viable approach?

Comment: Are you going to do this in xamarin forms? The automatic swipe should happen when and how many times? Please update your question with that info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it by using:

```
Device.StartTimer(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3), () =>
{   
    // run swipe code
    Task.WaitAll(_scvm.MoveNext());
    return true;
});
```

After the `InitialzeComponent()` line